# fallback-to-build error while installing Truffle in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: truffle

I was installing Truffle in Ubuntu 16.10 using `sudo` , but I got the following error message:

> npm WARN wrtc@0.0.63 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
>
> npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-59-generic
>
> npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
>
> npm ERR! node v6.10.3
>
> npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! wrtc@0.0.63 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!  Failed at the wrtc@0.0.63 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
> npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed. > npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the wrtc package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:  npm bugs wrtc npm
>
> Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: npm owner ls wrtc

Comment: It _seems_ this error is a bug in Ubuntu 16.10. Is a solution available?

Comment: Do you have all prerequisites of wrtc package installed? https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc#prerequisites

Comment: Yes, I have tried the apt-get prerequisite installation. The same error persists.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue on 16.10
Use --binary flag with truffle install command
And avoid -g, the modules are harder to track if instaĺled globally

Comment: Tried `sudo npm install --binary truffle`. Same error still.